# Comparing data when not all members of a population are measured at every time point?

Tags: time-series, missing-data

In multiple cases, I have data where there are populations that don't have data points at for some measurements (due to subjects passing away or otherwise).

If I wanted to, say, compute the mean of a particular measurement when some of my subjects didn't make it through to the end of the study, what is the/an appropriate method?

My colleagues and I have also run into situations where we have multiple populations, including one population with data at two distinct times (with some subjects who did not receive a second measurement), where we would like to perform various analyses but are unsure how to account for missing measurements in that particular subject population.

Am I forced to drop the subjects who don't have measurements at all time points? Or is there a different way? I've attached an example plot I threw together to demonstrate what I mean.

[image]